# Find the limit of $\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of $\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

In the previous part of the question I was asked to prove that as $n\to\infty$ $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\to log{2}$. I could do this considering the integral of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ from $(n+1)$ to $(2n+1)$ and from $(n)$ to $(2n)$ and then using the sandwich rule.

I guess I should use the same method somehow or this previous result.

Comment: What are the limits of the sum? Are we looking for the value of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}$?

Comment: @GeorgeS The sum apparently is
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k-n-1}}k$$

Comment: We are looking for the sum as as $n\to\infty$, edited now.

Comment: @moon1234 Are you allowed to use that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}k = \ln 2$$

Comment: I think I am. I haven't thought about that before.

Comment: Take $n$ common out , you will get an integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $n$ is even you can use successive differences to rewrite this sum as 
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}
$$
Here there are $n/2$ terms that are each bounded above by $1/n^2$, so the whole sum is bounded between $0$ and $1/2n$.  If $n$ is odd you can find a similar bound.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
You know that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}k = -\ln 2$$
If $S_N$ are the partial sums, your sum is
$$(-1)^{n-1} (S_{2n} - S_n)$$
Now because $S_n$ converges (to $-\ln2$), it is a Cauchy sequence. What does that tell you about
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} |S_{2n} - S_n| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k-n-1}}k \right| \qquad?$$

Comment: This means that the sum is tending to 0, right?

Comment: @moon1234 Exactly.

Comment: @AlexR There is a typo in your first equality :)

Comment: @OlivierOloa Fixed. Thanks for notifying :)